# wp_mail not working in my ajax function - functions.php file

Tags: ajax, wordpress, email

**WP_MAIL** functionality is not working in my **ajax** function in **functions.php** file.

Please have an look on the code and help me out !!

Do i need to load any files for the working of wp_mail function ??

```
function et_contact_form() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" >

  jQuery('#contact_modal').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
    var name    = jQuery("#name").val();

    var data    = {
                   'action':'et_contact_modal',
                   'name'  : name
                  };

     jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert(response);
     });    
});
</script> <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'et_contact_form' ); 

function et_contact_modal() {

global $wpdb;

$headers .= "Reply-To: test@gmail.com \r\n";
//$headers .= "CC: test@gmail.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$subject = 'New Enquiry From  ';
  $message .= '<p>' . $_POST['name'] . '</p>';
  $message .= '<p></p>';

  $mailResult = false;
  $mailResult = wp_mail( 'test@gmail.com',$subject,$message, $headers );
  echo $mailResult;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_et_contact_modal', 'et_contact_modal' );
```

Comment: Is it working when you logged in admin panel?

Comment: already it is logged in as admin .

Answer (score 0):

Sorry people's!!

The code was correct , it was just server issue !!

Thank you.